# What contradiction are we looking for when using proof by contradiction?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

If we want to prove a statement, "if $p$ is true, then $q$ is true", by using the technique of proof by contradiction, we would suppose that "$p$ and ~$q$ are true", then we derive a contradiction.

Assume that (~$q$ implies $w$) is true. If, by analyzing $p$, we determine that $w$ is not true, can we say that we have proved the original statement by contradiction?

Comment: Um........ yes?

Comment: Any contradiction will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> assume that (~$q$ implies $w$) is true

If you have subsequently derived—rather than are further *assuming*— that (~$q$ implies $w$) is true, then, since you have also derived that $w$ is false, by contrapositive, $q$ must be true. This contradicting your initial supposition that $(p$ and ~$q)$ is true indeed proves, by contradiction, the original statement.